# postgresql select fields from 2 tables where data in 2 tables

Tags: postgresql

I'm a total postgresql noob...

I have 3 tables : `Documents`, `Keywords` and the join table `Documents_Keywords`

**update**

I want to select the id and description from Documents and the keywords from keywords where the description or the keywords are like "certain" and "words" and are not "certain" and "other" and "words".

**end of update**

The first try I gave to this was :

```
SELECT actes.id
FROM actes JOIN "actes_motclefs"
    ON "motclefs"."id" = "actes_motclefs"."motclef_id"
WHERE ("motclefs"."motcle" LIKE "%éch%");
```

Comment: Your query does not appear to match the description.

Comment: correct... the query is only a beginning of an attempt.

Comment: Do you really have a many-to-many relationship between `documents` and `keywords` while a row in `keywords` still can contain multiple words? Or you just want to search for word parts too?

Comment: Yes I have a many-to-many relationship. A row in keywords can't contain multiple words. I've updated the question. I now do this :
 `SELECT DISTINCT "documents"."id","documents"."document_date" FROM "documents" INNER JOIN "documents_keywords" ON "documents_keywords"."document_id" = "document"."id" INNER JOIN "keywords" ON "keywords"."id" = "documents_keywords"."keyword_id" WHERE (document_date BETWEEN '900' AND '1400') AND (keyword = 'prébende');` I tried to make that last bit `AND (keyword = 'prébende') AND (keyword = 'pagus')` but that's not the way to do this.

Comment: @thiebo Try it without `DISTINCT`, but `... WHERE ... AND keyword IN ('prébende', 'pagus') GROUP BY documents.id HAVING COUNT(keywords.id) = 2` (assuming `id` is the primary key in both tables).

Comment: @pozs Thanks ! I now do this : `... WHERE (document_date BETWEEN '900' AND '1400') AND keywords.keyword IN ('stone', 'brick') GROUP BY documents.id` This functions like ` OR`, i.e. returns the documents that contain either "stone" or "brick". How should I draft it so it returns only the document that contain both?

Comment: @thiebo `HAVING COUNT(keywords.id) = 2` as I wrote. It will ensure, that only those documents will be returned, which have 2 matching keywords, each of which is either `stone` OR `brick` (or in other words: both of them). -- OFC, it will only work, when `keyword` is unique in `keywords` and the `documents_keywords` junction table only contains unique relations. -- you could use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT keyword) = 2` otherwise.

Comment: WORKS !!!! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT d.id, d.description, k.keywords
FROM documents d
JOIN documents_keywords dk
    ON d.id = dk.document_id
JOIN keywords k
    ON dk.keyword_id = k.id
WHERE (d.description LIKE '%certain%words%'
       OR k.keywords LIKE '%certain%words%') 
AND d.description NOT LIKE '%certain%other%words%'
AND k.keywords NOT LIKE '%certain%other%words%'
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't clear. Each keyword is a separate entry into the keywords table. So keywords can't be `'%certain%other%words%'`. I tried `WHERE ("k"."keywords" = 'certain' AND "k"."keywords" = 'other' AND "k"."keywords" = 'words')`  That clearly isn't working.